# Working with Pre-Aggregated Data in InfluxDB/Grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a data series that is only available in a pre-aggregated form where I have a value for each hourly time window. It represents the kWh consumed by a heater. Example below:

```
0000-0100, 9.8
0100-0200, 3.4
...
0800-0900, 1.3
0900-1000, 0.7
...
2300-0000, 1.2
```

I would like to record store this data in InfluxDB so it can be plotted in Grafana as a bar chart over different time periods so show the kWh consumed hourly, daily, weekly, monthly etc.

My initial thought it to store a data point in InfluxDB using the timestamp for the end time of the window, and the value itself. E.g.

```
(0100, 9.8)
(0200, 3.4)
```

Is this the "best" approach, or is there another way?